# If $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ show that $f'(x)$ is bounded.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ show that $f'(x)$ is bounded.

We have $f'(x)=\frac{\cos{x}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}-\frac{x\sin{x}}{(1+x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$. then $|f'(x)|\leq |\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}|+|\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}|$

How to show that $|f'(x)|<A$

Comment: Hint: $|x|\leqslant 1+x^2$ and $1+x^2 \geqslant 1$.

Comment: @ntt Thank you. I can do the rest. But how you get $|x|\leqslant 1+x^2$

Comment: since $$(|x|-1)^2\geq 0$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner 2 will come with |x|

Comment: yes ok $$|x|\le \frac{1+x^2}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $f'(x)$ is continuous, the *Boundedness theorem* shows it is enough to prove $\lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty}f'(x)=0$, which is obvious from the formula for $f'(x)$.